# Limit of Related Videos with Youtube Api 2.0

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I'm using the [YouTube Data API for .NET](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet).

I am calling the [`GetRelatedVideos` function](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r887/docs/folder56/M_Google_YouTube_YouTubeRequest_GetRelatedVideos.htm) on the [`YouTubeRequest` class](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r887/docs/folder56/T_Google_YouTube_YouTubeRequest.htm) and it returns 25 videos that are related to a video, like so:

```
Video video = Request.Retrieve<Video>(
    new Uri(String.Format("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{0}{1}",
        vID ,"?max-results=50&start-index=1")));  

Feed<Video> relatedVideos = Request.GetRelatedVideos(video);

return FillVideoInfo(relatedVideos.Entries);
```

Here is the request link:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1FJHYqE0RDg?max-results=50&start-index=1

But I get this error

> The 'max-results' parameter is not supported on this resource

If I just use:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1FJHYqE0RDg

Then I get 25 videos.  But I want to get 50 videos and and page for more.  I am able to get a result for the following URL:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1FJHYqE0RDg/related?max-results=50&start-index=1

Here I get a response, but but I only get 25 videos even though I passed 50 for the `max-results` parameters.

How can I get 50 related videos for a particular video at a time instead of the default 25 (50 is the max for `max-results`).

Comment: Going to https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1FJHYqE0RDg/related?max-results=50&start-index=1 I actually get 50 results in the browser.  Do you get 50 results when you just download the file in the browser?

Comment: @casperOne yes I get also 50 results but in code,relatedVideos  has 25 entries.. I dont know why.. and thank you for attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the URL string yourself, you should be using the properties on the [`YouTubeRequest` class](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r887/docs/folder56/AllMembers_T_Google_YouTube_YouTubeRequest.htm) to set them for you.

For example, when getting the [`Video`](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r887/docs/folder56/T_Google_YouTube_Video.htm) instance, you *don't* want to specify the [`PageSize` property](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r887/docs/folder54/P_Google_GData_Client_RequestSettings_PageSize.htm) on the [`YouTubeRequestSettings`](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r887/docs/folder56/T_Google_YouTube_YouTubeRequestSettings.htm) instance, like so:

```
// Create the request.
var request = new YouTubeRequest(
    new YouTubeRequestSettings("my app", null) { AutoPaging = false });

// Get the video.
var video = request.Retrieve<Video>(
    new Uri("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1FJHYqE0RDg"));
```

However, you want to use a *different* `YouTubeRequestSettings` attached to the `YouTubeRequest` instance when making the call to [`GetRelatedVideos` method](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r887/docs/folder56/M_Google_YouTube_YouTubeRequest_GetRelatedVideos.htm):

```
// Create the request again.  Set the page size.
request = new YouTubeRequest(
    new YouTubeRequestSettings("my app", null) { 
        AutoPaging = false, PageSize = 50
 });

 // Get the related videos.
 var related = request.GetRelatedVideos(video);
```

Now it will return 50 videos.  If you try and set the `PageSize` property when getting the video, you get an error because the `max-results` parameter is invalid when getting a single video.

You can then write out the count of the entries to validate that 50 are returned:

```
// Write out how many videos there are.
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
    "{0} related videos in first page.", related.Entries.Count()));
```

The result will be:

> 50 related videos in first page.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I solved my own program like what you mentioned that..    Feed<Video> relatedVideos = Request.Get<Video>(new Uri(String.Format("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{0}/related?{1}", vID, GetYoutubeParemeters()))); //"?max-results=25&start-index=1&orderby=relevance")));
                      
                    return FillVideoInfo(relatedVideos.Entries);   But your mention is better and the truest one. Thank you very much for your interesting..